# Audio controls appear on mouseover and fade away on mouseout

Tags: javascript, html, css, audio-player

What I want to do is to make audio controls be visible on page load, fade out after 5 seconds, appear on hover/mouseover and fade out 5 seconds after mouse out. Exactly like how the YouTube control bar works.

```html
<audio controls>
  <source src="horse.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>
```

Comment: When the controls disappear, what does user hover over to make them re-appear?

Comment: (lol, I've jumped in the deep end) A placeholder. but i dont know how to do those.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#audio-placeholder').hover(
       function(){
         //runs on mouseover
         $('#audio-controls').fadeIn();
       },
       function(){
         //runs on mouseout
         hideAudioControls(); 
       }
   );
  hideAudioControls(); //runs at startup
});

function hideAudioControls(){
   setTimeout(function(){
     $('#audio-controls').fadeOut();
   },3000);
}
```

```css
div{position:relative;}
.audio-inner{position:absolute;top:0;left:0;}
#audio-controls{background:white;z-index:1;}
#audio-placeholder{width:300px;height:20px;padding-top:10px;text-align:center;z-index:0;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="audio-container">
  <div id="audio-controls" class="audio-inner">
    <audio controls>
      <source src="horse.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
       Your browser does not support the audio element.
    </audio>
  </div>
  <div id="audio-placeholder" class="audio-inner">
     Hover here for controls
  </div>
</div>
```

Notes:

Basically, there is one box (audio-container) that contains two other boxes.

The audio-container box must be styled `position:relative` for the `position:absolute` to work in the other two boxes. `position-absolute` makes the two boxes go one on top of the other, so I also used `z-index` to tell it which box is on top (`z-index:1`) and which is on bottom (`z-index:0`) *Note that you can make up any number for z-index - the bigger number is on top of the lower number.*

`hover()` takes two functions - the first fires on mouseover, and the second fires on mouseout.

The javascript code uses jQuery, so you must reference it in your document (as done in the example code.)

Comment: thanks so much. I just wanted to know how to implement the jquery. is it similar to external css?

Comment: Exactly like in the above example. You can place exactly that script tag anywhere in your body, but most people would place it either at the very end of the body, just before the `</body>` tag (that is probably optimal), or else way up top (above the `<body>` tag) between the `<head></head>` tags is also very popular.

Comment: oh, I solved it. lol, I was linking to a local version of jquery _itself_ (ajax.googleapis.com) never worked with jquery before but once I realised what i was doing it worked like it should. Thanks for all your help.

Comment: You are welcome. jQuery makes writing javascript significantly easier. There are some decent free video tutorials over on [the New Boston](http://thenewboston.com). *Enjoy.*